# cURL XML REST POST in Java Android

Tags: java, android, rest, post, curl

How can I convert this statement in cURL `curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/xml" -H "Accept: application/xml" -d "<ticket><summary>This is a Summary</summary><priority>3</priority></ticket>" http://user:password@www.assembla.com/spaces/my_space_id/tickets` to Java in Android? The most important part is how to invoke the XML in the URL?

Answer (score 1):

Use [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html), specifically `HttpPost` for your POST request. The `-H` switches turn into `addHeader()` calls. You would probably just use a `StringEntity` for the XML payload, though I haven't tried a non-urlencoded POST with HttpClient before.

Comment: Could you give me the JAVA code please? I've tried using StringEntity but it didn't work. I probably did it wrong, but I don't know the correct way to do it.